# Are the fields 'Amount remaining' and 'Amount remaining is above 0' exposed in Netsuite. If not is there a workaround for the same?

Tags: typescript

I'm working on replicating the below saved search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM TRANSACTIONS T
INNER JOIN  TRANSACTION_LINES  TL ON T.TRANSACTION_ID=TL.TRANSACTION_ID
WHERE  (TL.AMOUNT-TL.AMOUNT_LINKED)>0
```

This should work.